# Best Performance SQL Query SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m building a report and I’m in a dilemma which path to follow to reach better performance.

I got a table where

```
COD | CTYPID | MNT
```

The above contains `COD` as the primary key, type and amount

The report will contain each type as a column. Meaning one `COD` will have 3 columns for each `CTYPID`.

Which one is the best:

1-

```
   Insert into #temp
   Select sum(amount),CTYPID From table
   Group by COD,CTYPIDz
```

Then I left join this table with my main table where CTYPID=1
Then another left join where CTYPID=2 and so one

2-

```
 --insert in a temp table on multiple columns
   insert into #temp
   (Select sum(amount) column1,CTYPID From table where CTYPID=1
   Group by COD)
   Left join (Select sum(amount)column2 ,CTYPID From table where CTYPID=2
   Group by COD)
```

Then join the above with my main table

Comment: When you tested both approaches, reviewed run time, and reviewed impact on your system, which did you find performed better?

Comment: *"Which one is the best:"* impossible to answer when we don't have the DDL of your tables, and indexes of your objects; or know the size of the data you're working with. I suggest you test and find out.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative option would be to do conditional aggregation:

```
insert into #temp
select
    cod,
    sum(case when ctypid = 1 then mnt else 0 end) mnt_ctypid1,
    sum(case when ctypid = 2 then mnt else 0 end) mnt_ctypid2,
    sum(case when ctypid = 3 then mnt else 0 end) mnt_ctypid3
from mytable 
group by cod
```

For this query, you want an index on `(cod, ctypid)` (which might be already there since this seems to - or should - be the primary key of your table).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Seems neat and I can use one query to get all the data I need. Thank you

Comment: Actually after trying this solution it won’t work as desired. I’d need to include ctypid on the group by causing the results to spread on different rows for each ctypid. I found it best to join multiple times on dynamic selects and get the totals for each ctypid on each join. I was able to get the result on different columns